How to efficiently apply a `spacy` model to encode an entire `pandas` dataframe?
I am trying to implement a semantic search where I have to match a query string over a corpus that is present in a pandas dataframe. I am trying to use spacy and its similarity function to compute the similarity between two items of text. To pass it to the similarity function, first I need to encode the entire dataframe using a model (Here I am using their en_core_web_md pre-trained pipeline to get the vectors).
How can I do this efficienty over multiple large dataframes? Currently I'm just using the pandas map function to apply the model to every item in the dataframe.
import spacy
import pandas as pd
import nltk

nltk.download('words')

from nltk.corpus import words

def main():
    query_string = "Eat Apple"

    # Generate a sample corpus using words from nltk
    data = [words.words()[:1000] for _ in range(5)]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data).T

    compute_semantic_match_score(df, query_string)

def compute_semantic_match_score(df, query):
    model = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

    data_embeddings = df.map(model)
    query_embedding = model(query)
    match_scores = data_embeddings.map(query_embedding.similarity)
    print(match_scores)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()

Here I am using a sample dataframe generated from an nltk corpus for a minimum reproducible example.
However in the limited compute environment where this is going to be deployed, this takes a considerable amount of time to execute. Is there a more efficient way to apply the model over the entire dataframe?
The reference dataframes only change infrequently so I can consider pre-computing the values for the data and storing them on disk. However I'd prefer to do the processing live if possible.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!
